# In SQL Query, use CASE to print desired result if condition is met

Tags: sql, case

I have a condition where I want to display a status of Approved or Rejected. I have been given a database which was created by someone and is in a mess. Not structured. I have a table with names and process_code like below for example :

```
name | process_code
A    |  7
B    |  7
C    |  3
D    |  4
...
```

What I want to achieve is if the process_code is 7, it will return a status of Rejected. If the process_code is other than 7, it will return Approved.

It looks something like this :

```
SELECT name, process_code AS Status 
CASE process_code
WHEN '7' THEN 'Rejected'
ELSE 'Approved'
FROM association
```

It didn't work. Can someone guide to correct my sql query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just missing the `end` of the case when clause, and a comma (and not sure you need quotes around process_code).

```
SELECT 
     name, 
     process_code AS Status,
     CASE process_code
       WHEN '7' THEN 'Rejected'
       ELSE 'Approved'
     END
FROM association
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need a comma before the case and you need an `end`:

```
SELECT name, process_code AS Status, 
       (CASE process_code
            WHEN '7' THEN 'Rejected'
            ELSE 'Approved'
        END)
FROM association;
```

If the code is actually an integer, you might need to make the comparison without the single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

These answers are useful for you but you can do it like this:

```
SELECT name, CASE WHEN process_code='7' THEN process_code+'- Rejected' ELSE process_code+'- Approved' END as Status
FROM association;
```

If your process_code is int, you must cast the process_code and then plus the string expression.

```
SELECT name, CASE WHEN process_code=7 THEN CAST(process_code as VARCHAR)+'- Rejected' ELSE CAST(process_code as VARCHAR)+'- Approved' END as Status
FROM association;
```

Comment: How did you guess the dbms ?